# Rails -- Sending All Unaccepted Invites from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

From the rails console I need to be able to send all unaccepted invites in my rails app's Postgres database. (I have a table called Invitations with a boolean field called accepted).

From the console the following code successfully finds all of the unaccepted invites and stores only the first one in a variable. The next line only sends that one.

```
invitation = Invitation.find_by(accepted: 'FALSE')
invitation.send!
```

How do I store all of the unaccepted invitations into a variable and then use invitation.send! to send them? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
Invitation.where(accepted: 'FALSE').each do |inv|
  inv.send!
end
```

---

You could also use [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) as [lest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256556/lest)  suggested in the comment below.

```
Invitation.where(accepted: 'FALSE').find_each do |inv|
  inv.send!
end
```

---

One-liner, as suggested by [meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar):

```
Invitation.where(accepted: 'FALSE').find_each(&:send!)
```

---

If you explicitly wanted to store all unaccepted invitations to a variable first, you could do this:

```
unaccepted_invitations = Invitation.where(accepted: 'FALSE')
```

Then you could iterate through them with one of the loops above, just replace the `Invitation.where(accepted: 'FALSE')` with the `unaccepted_invitations` variable.

Comment: I'd suggest using `#find_each` instead of `#each` to process records in batches that will be useful in case there are a lot of unaccepted invites in the DB.

Comment: FYI: `Invitation.where(accepted: 'FALSE').find_each(&:send!)`

Comment: Just so future readers know, meagar's solution worked perfectly

`Invitation.where(accepted: 'FALSE').find_each(&:send!) 'code'`